# How to use Bootstrap 5.3 to position a navigation bar to the right?

Tags: navigation, frontend, alignment, bootstrap-5, navigationbar

This is my code.

```html
<nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Tindog</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

I tried to use the position in Bootstrap but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You indicate that you use bootstrap 5.3, but you do use bootstrap 4 < classes and data attributes.

For example, one no longer uses `data-target` but `data-bs-target`.
You also still use the margin-left class `ml-auto` but bootstrap 5+ uses "start" and "end" so you have to use `ms-auto`.

You have added the `ms-auto` to `<ul>`, but to get the desired result you need to add it to the `<li>` element.

**Example:**

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar bg-dark navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark px-3">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Tindog</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse p-2" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item ms-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact (ms-auto)</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item mx-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing (mx-auto)</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```